# How Spark handle partial output task

Tags: scala, apache-spark, time

I am currently measuring the processing time of a particular transform operation, say:

```
val t0 = System.nanoTime()
val newdf = olddf.select($"text").filter(x=>x.contains(TEXT))
val newdf.show(10)
val t1 = System.nanoTime()
println("processing time:", t1-t0)
```

In such case, because only 10 rows will be shown after the transform, I am wondering if Spark is smart enough to simply process first 10 rows, and then stop the job.

If so, how to measure the processing time, for the whole task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot to unpack here:

1. Yes, Spark is generally "smart enough" to "process first 10 rows, and then stop the job"
2. To be more precise - the "job" here *is* to "show first 10 rows". The *transformations* leading up to it are part of that same job, and are only performed when the job is executed.
3. You can't really measure just the transformation alone (`select` and `filter`) - these are never executed outside the context of *some* action (like `show`, `write`, `collect` etc.), so measure the "processing time" does not really make sense if you mean the `select` and `filter` time - these do not really represent any "processing"
4. Spark's internal model devides the work into Jobs, Stages and Tasks - and these are measured effectively by Spark itself. So it's better to use Spark's [UI](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#web-interfaces) (or [REST API](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api)) for such measurements, instead of trying to time them yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One more question, since using show(10) will let Spark only process 10 rows. Which "action" function will let Spark process the whole dataframe. Persist() ?

Comment: You can try using `foreach` with a function that does nothing (`newdf.foreach(ignored => {})` - that would force Spark to apply the method to all records. But again, what you'll actually be measuring is this `foreach` and the way the transformations were applied to accomplish it - it would be hard to conclude anything about the "processing time" of the transformations before it.